# Session Flush in laravel must retain Auth details

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

Whenever I use SessionFlush all session details is lost, How can I prevent session flush to not remove my Auth in laravel so the user will not get logout. Im using laravel 5.4

Comment: show a code at least. what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save user in variable, flush all session data, login user.

```
$user = Auth::user();
$request->session()->flush();
Auth::login($user);
// return response or return redirect
```

Comment: It should mean you want some 2or less  liner here for what you want. From your question this code does exactly what you want imho. Is there some more requirements/logic needs to be included?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to just remove the piece of information you want out of the session? A `session()->flush()` will remove everything.

Something like:

```
$request->session()->forget('theKeyToRemove');
// or
Session::forget('theKeyToRemove');
// or
session()->forget('theKeyToRemove');
```

Comment: Yes but I want to use flush to refresh all my session.